# Check if Resource type is Static Resource or Document Resource

Tags: if-statement, modx-revolution, television

I wanted to know what is the right syntax on a conditional statement way to check if a Resource used is static or Document? I have a single template that can be used with 2 different types of resource.

So the conditional statement might be like this:

> [[+template:is=`static`:then=`This is static resource`:else=`This is
>   document resource`]]

Anyone knows how to do it in MODx? I'm using MODx revolution latest version.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to check the [[*class_key]] variable of the resource in question.

```
[[+class_key:is='modDocument':then='This is document resource']]
```

you also have modWebLink & modSymLink, I don't know what the static resource is ~ at a guess modStatic?

Answer (score 0):

this is coming a lot later but just for the benefit of those that may come along later, the key for static resource is modStaticResource.